# unexpected out put from char **name, c

Tags: c, arrays, regex, pcre, boost-regex

Am in my way to practice how to use the [pcre regex library](http://www.pcre.org/), to match [regular expression/pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) against a given data/buffer.Then if there is match, i have to load the matched string to may array/list. but, when i print my list/array (using a for loop), the output is unexpected/wrong. pls see how the logic works:

1.first i have to load patterns/regex.....i have a function to do this and returns patterns in an array/list.

2.iterate on each pattern and search for match in a data/buffer....pcre library handles this business.

3.if match exists, push/fill to a list/array

4.print out all matches with in loop

**my sample code is:**
code.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pcre.h>
#define NUMBER 3
#define MAX_GROUPS 200

char *data = "Jun 12 05 12:24:48 100.101.102.103 end";
char **load_patern()
{
    char **regex_array = malloc (sizeof (char *) * NUMBER);
    regex_array[0] = "(\\w+\\s\\d+\\s\\d+\\s\\d+:\\d+:\\d+)"; //pattern to match date time
    regex_array[1] = "(\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)"; //pattern for ip_adress
    regex_array[2] = "(end)";//pattern for "end"

  return regex_array;
}

int main()
{
        char **patern_list = load_patern();
        int t,i,size,rc,p,re_err_offset,re_vce[MAX_GROUPS];
        char sBuffer[512];
        char *pLasts = NULL;
        pcre *re_compiled;
        pcre_extra *re_extra;
        const char *re_err_str;
        char *token,*logg,*next,*match_str;

        char **struct_list = malloc (sizeof (char *) * NUMBER);
        for(t=0;t<3;t++) //3 is number of patterns, patern_list size
        {
            snprintf(sBuffer, sizeof(sBuffer), "%s",data);
            pLasts = sBuffer;
            re_compiled = pcre_compile(patern_list[t], 0, &re_err_str, 

&re_err_offset, NULL);
                re_extra = pcre_study(re_compiled, 0, &re_err_str);
                next = pLasts;
                size = strlen(pLasts);
                rc = pcre_exec(re_compiled, re_extra, next, size, 0, 0, re_vce, MAX_GROUPS);
                if(rc>0) //if match exists
                {
                    next[re_vce[3]] = '\0';
                    match_str = next + re_vce[2];
                    struct_list[t] = match_str;
                    printf("data at [%d]:%s\n",t,struct_list[t]);//this prints correctly
                }
            }
//but,here am trying to print each match stored in struct_list[], but it fails to display correctly.
            for(p=0; p<3; p++)
            {
                printf("loop_one: [%d]----%s\n",p,struct_list[p]);
            }
        return 0;
    }
```

The out put from a loop iterating on p,should be:

```
loop_one: 0----Jun 12 05 12:24:48
loop_one: 1----100.101.102.103
loop_one: 2----end
```

any thing i miss?

Comment: `(\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)` -> `(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)`

Comment: You really should make all those pointers `const` and use const correctness.

Comment: hay@WiktorStribiżew: the problem is not with my pattern, when i check my out put with in **if(rc>0)** condition, my out put is correct. it prints all the three matches,but not in my last for loop. thanks.

Comment: @Lundin: making pointers const, dosn*t fix the problem. can you run my sample code and see the printout.? am on linux(centos 6.5): **gcc -o exc code.c -lpcre**. thanks.

Comment: @kahsay.k That would be why I posted it as a comment, not an answer. Using const correctness solves problems in general, it might fix _future_ problems with your code. And no thanks, I have no interest in debugging this code.